# send video stream byte-byte to the clients

Tags: php, proxy, php-stream-wrappers

I have one question.

Imagine, that video files are in the server named **A**.

using php script (which is in the server named **"B"**) we **can** get stream of the video **(from the server "A" to the server "B")**. The important thing is that only **B** server cant get video stream. It is forbidden for the other servers.

**PROBLEM**:
There are many client  and they want to download videos from the server named **"A"**.

**There is only one solution:** 
video files must be downloaded through the server "B".  can you tell me, how can I do that?

For instance lets get youtube video. **I upload his script to my server "B". this script downloads videos to the server, but how to send video stream to the clients via the server (through the server B)? I need to send video byte to byte to the client , I don't want to save video to the server, I want to sent byte to byte to the client.** When the server downloads 100 byte , it should save it in the memory , and sent to client, then again download and save to the server memory and send to the client... something like this...

for "sending to client" I mean - to open  "save as dialog" of  browser of the client

```
<?php
    $id = "BZP1rYjoBgI"; 
    $format = "video/mp4"; 
    ...

    $videoStream = .....;

    ...

    }
?>
```

Comment: client should have servers proxy? how this? can you explane me?

Comment: So basically, you want to steal videos from servers which doesn't allow downloads and make them downloadable to your users? Am I missing something?